# Can I use AdSense for a single domain with some pages not followed policy?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I have a web blog and I want to write some ethical hacking, hacking mitigation and not hacking related content.

Can I include AdSense for only pages that follows policy and not include in pages that break policy ?

AdSense policy apply to a domain or just pages includes AdSense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Adsense guidelines are on a per-page basis. You are basically forbidden to place your code on those that don't follow policy.

> When you monetize your content with Google ad code you are required to
> adhere to the following policies. By content we mean anything present
> **on your page or app** - including other advertisements and links to
> other sites or apps. Failure to comply with these policies may result
> in Google blocking ads from appearing against your content, or
> suspending or terminating your account.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9335564?hl=en

They have algorithms that continually check for policy violations and will notify you of them. If you have multiple violations it can trigger a manual review, which may result in a sitewide manual penalty, that although not impossible, it's very hard to get out of.